# Sails server not started

Tags: node.js, sails.js, forever

I'm trying to run my app with the following command :

```
forever start /var/www/app.js --prod
```

But I have this error :

```
To run an app using `node app.js`, you usually need to have a version of `sails` installed in the same directory as your app.
To do that, run `npm install sails`

Alternatively, if you have sails installed globally (i.e. you did `npm install -g sails`), you can use `sails lift`.
When you run `sails lift`, your app will still use a local `./node_modules/sails` dependency if it exists,
but if it doesn't, the app will run with the global sails instead!
```

Sails is already installed on the same directory. Forever is installed globally.

I also test

```
node app.js --prod
```

But same error so it's not because of forever.

I'm under node V4.1.1 and npm v3.3.4. `sails lift` work great.

Comment: Have you tried to do what a error message suggests?

Comment: Yes :) also try to remove node-modules/sails and npm install it again but no luck...

Comment: Have you tried running $ npm install, and then run, $ forever start app.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got it working! 
Some of sails dependency doesn't correctly installed, I have removed all the node_modules folder of my project and `npm install` again and now it's working.

The error message is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with Sails installed globally ?

Comment: Thanks ! I try sails globally (or not). I found the problem see my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
cd /var/www
forever start app.js --prod
```

Please try this way and tell if it worked.

Comment: Thanks ! Yes I have try. Finally I found the problem see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the .sailsrc file in the app
Mine was having fault with the comma being left out

```
"generators": {
    "modules": {},
}
```

removing the comma worked for me